# MySQL — Filesystem Normalized or Denormalized?

Tags: mysql, filesystems, normalization

I'm working on an app that will allow users to upload media and organize their media into folders. The user can determine the "type" of folder they create: Folder, Videos, Images, Documents, etc.

The app will display the contents of any given folder differently depending on its type; a Video folder will display a video player with a playlist, an images folder will display a gallery, etc.

Would it be better to create separate tables for all the different types of folders or create one large table called FOLDERS with a column to assign the type?

The actual media itself is handled by its own table called MEDIA and then linked into a folder using a media_ID.

**In short: How does an OS handle this? Is there one master 'table' called FOLDERS and then the various files are linked to a folder using a file_ID?**

**EDIT: To clarify, here's how the 'single folders table' approach would break down:**

```
FOLDERS
...................
id
user_ID
parent_ID
type
date

MEDIA
...................
id
type
file
date

FOLDERS_link_MEDIA
...................
id
folder_ID
media_ID
```

So when a user adds MEDIA to a FOLDER a row is created in the FOLDERS_link_MEDIA table connecting the two.

The alternative, as I see it, would be to have several 'folders' tables FOLDERS_video, FOLDERS_audio, FOLDERS_images, FOLDERS_documents, etc. And then an accompanying linking table for each folder type; FOLDERS_video_link_MEDIA table, FOLDERS_images_link_MEDIA, etc.

Also, the actual data of the files will NOT be stored in the MEDIA table, the 'file' column simply stores a URL that points to where the file is stored on AWS S3.

Thanks.

**EDIT 2: The SQL**

And here's how I would go about traversing the table(s). If I were to pull up the contents of a folder I would first determine if there are any child folders that belong to the current folder:

```
SELECT id FROM FOLDERS WHERE parent_ID='$this_folder_ID';
```

And then I would display those folders to the user (folders on top!). And then I would proceed to get any MEDIA contents:

```
SELECT media_ID FROM FOLDERS_link_MEDIA WHERE folder_ID='$this_folder_ID';
```

Comment: It depends on what data you intend to store in the database. What data do you intend to store in the database?

Comment: Hi Mark. The data is pretty basic for any given folder: id, parent_ID, title, date. I've edited above to illustrate.

Comment: Your proposed structure looks fine as it is, with just one obvious problem: MySQL doesn't support recursive CTEs, so a single query wouldn't be able to traverse the entire file hierarchy, assuming you can have folders within folders. (Dedicated tables for each folder type wouldn't resolve this problem either.) You may want to look into the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way certainly - is a FAT - a File Allocation Table. (variations exist)
this tells the location of the file on disk.

what you have described sounds more like a 'type' than a folder.  your MEDIA entries should just have an enumerated type - then they will all be grouped together this when you query.

for instance you have not described if it is possible to have a Video that is not in the Video folder.

if you must, then create another table 'Folder' similar to this:

```
FOLDER
------------
folder_id
type_id
name
```

then use the same type_id values as you do for the MEDIA.

to make folder trees, something like this:

```
FOLDER_TREE
-------------
parent_folder_id
child_folder_id
```

to add MEDIA to the folders something like this:

```
FOLDER_CONTENT
-----------------
folder_id
media_id
```

Comment: Hi Randy. Yes, a user will be able to put any type of media into any type of folder. For example, if you put a video in a documents folder the system would not throw an exception. The folder types are used to determine the interface that is presented: video player for a video type folder, image gallery for an image type folder, etc.

So, if a user puts a video in an images folder the app itself wouldn't throw an exception, just the media would not play since it's a video file trying to be viewed as an image.

Comment: so this is usually done via an association of the type (mime type) to the list of applications that register to open that type - all on the file level, not the folder level.  as a user, i would be confused if my image didnt show up because i put it in a video folder..

Comment: Thanks Randy, but I think there's some confusion between us. The media-type/folder-type relationship is less important. What I'm really trying to figure out is if its good practice to split *any* folder types into multiple tables or if all folder types should reside in one table with a 'type' column to denote its type. Essentially: does an OS  store all its folders in one big table or does it have multiple tables for each type. For example, OSX has a Downloads folder, a Documents folder, an Images folder, etc. (cont'd)...

Comment: Are those "special" folders stored in the same main "folders" table and denoted by a type column or are they given their own special table?

Comment: those are all just folders - with names